# How to fix require.js's version querystring to not be put after a # (anchor) component

Tags: javascript, addthis

Require.js seems to be adding ?v= at the end of my http requests for versioning.

Unfortunately, it is adding it blindly to the end of the URL.  It should be inserting the query string right before any '#' characters (anchor) if present

The server of course should ignore any query string found to the right of the hash.

This seems to be the issue, breaking our current instance of AddThis's stats.

Does require.js provide a way to remedy this?

*EDIT*:
This was not at all a require.js issue, and I have removed the require.js tag.  It turned out to be internal code creating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in the library. See if it's mentioned here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues if not, report it.

Comment: RequireJS (the project mentioned in the answer) does not add any querystrings to the URLs unless you are using the urlArgs config value, and those URLs should not have fragment IDs (#part) on them since they are used for script fetching, not for loading web pages.

Perhaps it is a different require.js file from a different project that is in use.

Comment: jrburke, you're totally right.  There turned out to be some really tricky internal code doing this.  I found it right before posting a defect but forgot to reply to this.  I'll leave the question up as Addthis's use of # for params is tricky and querystrings might be causing an issue for them.